# Mac OS X: How Programmatically Set Display Turn Off To Never?

Tags: macos

I have connected BLE devices, but after specific time display turn off, BLE devices are disconnected. So i want programmatically to set display turn off to never.This option is of energy saver of system preferences.

Comment: http://mikeabdullah.net/power-assertions.html

Comment: `sudo pmset -a displaysleep 0 disksleep 10 sleep 30 womp 1` maybe?

Comment: Hi Sergio Sir, Thank you for your great answer!. It's worked for me. Before this I tried with kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep but didn't work for my scenario. Now BLE device didn't disconnect if the machine is in an ideal state. I have tested it for 2:00 hrs and it worked fine. Thanks once again.